# ADS v1.2 Error C2304E: <command> expected but found 'int'

Tags: c, compiler-errors, arm

Trying to write a code in ADS 1.2 but keep getting error C2304E: command expected but found 'int'/'unsigned'. I personally can't find anything wrong with the code and it runs normally on other compilers. Does anyone have the same problem? This is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 288
#define M 352
#define filename "akiyo_cif_0_yuv420.yuv"
unsigned char current_y[N][M];
unsigned char temp;

void read() {
    FILE *frame_c;
    if((frame_c=fopen(filename,"rb"))==NULL) {
        printf("current frame doesn't exist\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<M;j++) {
            temp=fgetc(frame_c);
            if (temp = fgetc(frame_c) == EOF) {
                /* error OR end-of-file */
                    ;
            }
            else
                current_y[i][j] = (char)temp;
        }
    }
    fclose(frame_c);
}
int main() {
    read();
    unsigned char *Img =& current_y[0][0]; //Error C2304E: command expected but found 'unsigned'
    int result = CLAHE (Img,352,288,0,227,2,2,256,3); //Error C2304E: command expected but found 'int'
    printf("%d",result);
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `current_y`

Comment: unsigned char current_y[352][288]; it's a global variable

Comment: I suspect something is wrong before the error location, confusing the compiler.

Comment: You mean inside read? This is the code i used: `void read()  
{  
  FILE *frame_c;  
  if((frame_c=fopen(filename,"rb"))==NULL)  
  {  
    printf("current frame doesn't exist\n");  
    exit(-1);  
  }  
  
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)  
  {  
    for(j=0;j<M;j++)  
    {  
      temp=fgetc(frame_c);  
   if (temp = fgetc(frame_c) == EOF) { /* error OR end-of-file */; }  
  else current_y[i][j] = (char)temp;  
    }  
  }  
  fclose(frame_c);  
}`

Comment: Please show declaration of all your variables: current_y, filename, temp, N, M

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `#define N 288 
#define M 352  
#define filename "akiyo_cif_0_yuv420.yuv" 
unsigned char current_y[N][M];
unsigned char temp;`

Comment: OK. and now the includes. Note `temp` must be `int` to be able to check for `EOF`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>`

Comment: So the above is your full program?

Comment: i and j are not declared in read.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Nope. It also includes the CLAHE function which is way too big but you can find it here: https://github.com/erich666/GraphicsGems/blob/master/gemsiv/clahe.c NOTE: I didnt use the typedef kz_pixel_t since I want it to run on 8bit per pixel images only. Also i have declared i and j as global variables too: `int i,j;`

Comment: I think I get it: you call `read` before declaring `Img`. Try calling `read` _after_ declaring it.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie hmm this works but the next error still persists. New main: `unsigned char *Img;
 read();
 Img =& current_y[0][0];
 int result = CLAHE (Img,352,288,0,227,2,2,256,3);
 printf("%d",result);` PS sorry for the formating, cant figgure out line breaks in comments still

Comment: Sidenote: `current_y[i][j] = (char)temp` - don't cast unless there is absolute need and you know why the cast is needed. This one is useless at best, potentially a bug, depending on the signed-ness of `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arm says on its website:

> The ARM Compiler toolchain ... supports full ISO standard C and C++.

But I can't find which version specifically of the C standard. Newer versions allow the declaration of variables anywhere in a block, but older versions of C require variables to be declared at the *top* of the block. From our trying in the comments it seems Arm supports this older version of C. So change your main to:

```
int main() {
    unsigned char *Img =& current_y[0][0];
    int result = CLAHE (Img,352,288,0,227,2,2,256,3);
    read();  // executable statements only after declaring variables.
    printf("%d",result);
}
```

Comment: Current versions of the ARM compiler toolchain support the `--c99` command line argument which will allow declaration anywhere in a block.  ADS is legacy though (RVDS replaced it) so I'm not sure if this option exists.

Comment: There is only one ISO standard for each language. With a new release the previous version is explicitly withdrawn.